# Sagemaker nbextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am running the following script in my Sagemaker notebook's lifecycle configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# OVERVIEW
# This script installs a single pip package in a single SageMaker conda environments.

sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=python3

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

pip install "PyAthena"
pip install "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator"
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --sys-prefix
pip install "jupyter_contrib_nbextensions"
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --sys-prefix

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate

EOF
```

When I open the notebook, I do not see the nbextensions tab. I have stopped and restart the notebook.

[image]

I have tried the subcommand lines with --user as well...

```
pip install "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator"
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
pip install "jupyter_contrib_nbextensions"
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this sample to [install notebook extensions](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-nb-extension/on-start.sh) on SageMaker notebooks.

You'd have to activate the JupyterSystemEnv for extensions. If you want a specific conda environment, such as Python3, to have a set of packages, then you can activate the `python3` environment and run `pip install <package>` commands.